# ListBox for ArgumentNullException Parameter name: source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, html.listboxfor

### Setup:

I have scaffolded a controller using MvcScaffolding.

For a property, Model.IdCurrencyFrom, the scaffolding created an Html.DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdCurrencyFrom, 
    ((IEnumerable<FlatAdmin.Domain.Entities.Currency>)ViewBag.AllCurrencies).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.CurrencyName), 
        Value = option.CurrencyId.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model != null) && (option.CurrencyId == Model.IdCurrencyFrom)
    }), "Choose...")
```

This works fine, both with new records, or editing existing ones.

### Problem:

There are only 3 currencies, AR$, US$ and GB£.  So, instead of a drop down list, I want a ListBox.

So I changed the above to:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.IdCurrencyFrom, 
    ((IEnumerable<FlatAdmin.Domain.Entities.Currency>)ViewBag.AllCurrencies).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.CurrencyName), 
        Value = option.CurrencyId.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model != null) && (option.CurrencyId == Model.IdCurrencyFrom)
    }))
```

I now get an ArgumentNullException, Parameter name: source, but only when editing an existing record.  Creating new records, this works fine.

### Questions:

What is happening?!

Nothing has changed.  Switching back to DropDownListFor and it all works fine.  Switching to ListBox (as opposed to ListBoxFor) and I get the error.

The model is not null (like I said, it works fine with the DropDownListFor)... and I've run out of ideas.

Comment: I noticed you're not checking if `option == null` on the `Value` line. Was that just an oversight?

Comment: The error you're getting is the `ViewBag.AllCurrencies` is null. I would definitely check to make sure it's not null in your action method. I know you said it's not null but the `source` parameter refers to the `Select` method parameter.

Comment: @BuildStarted:  It isn't null. As stated in the body of the question, it works fine with DropDownListFor.  Same code, same context.

Comment: @awrigley can you also post the code for your model? You can edit the question and add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've checked the source of the HTML helpers, it was a fun exercise.

TL;DR;
The problem is that ListBoxFor is for multiple selection and it expects an enumerable Model property. Your Model property (`model.IdCurrencyFrom`) is not an enumerable that's why you get the exception.

Here are my findings:

1. The ListBoxFor method will render a `select` element with `multiple="multiple"` attribute, always. It is hard coded in `System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions`

   ```
   private static MvcHtmlString ListBoxHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes) {
       return SelectInternal(htmlHelper, null /* optionLabel */, name, selectList, true /* allowMultiple */, htmlAttributes);
   }
   ```

   So maybe you anyway don't want to allow for the user multiple currencies...
2. Your problem starts when this ListBoxHelper tries to get the default value from your model property:

   ```
   object defaultValue = (allowMultiple) ? htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string[])) : htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));
   ```

   It works for DropDownList because it passes false to `allowMultiple` when calling `SelectInternal`.
   Because your `ViewData.ModelState` is empty (because there were no validation occurred in your controller before) the `defaultValue` will be `null`. Then `defaultValue` gets initialized with your model's default value (your case `model.IdCurrencyFrom` is `int` I guess) so it will be `0`. :

   ```
   if (!usedViewData) {
           if (defaultValue == null) {
               defaultValue = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(fullName);
           } 
    }
   ```

   We are getting close to the exception :) Because as I mentioned ListBoxFor only support multiple selection, so it tries to handle `defaultValue` as `IEnumbrable`:

   ```
   IEnumerable defaultValues = (allowMultiple) ? defaultValue as IEnumerable : new[] { defaultValue };
   IEnumerable<string> values = from object value in defaultValues select Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
   ```

   And in the second line there is your ArgumentException because `defaultValues` is `null`.
3. Because it expects `defaultValue` to be enumerable and because string is enumerable. If you change the the type of `model.IdCurrencyFrom` to `string` it will work. But of course you will have multiple selection on the UI but you will only get the first selection in your model.